# php image upload not creating thumbnail

Tags: php, file-upload, thumbnails, image-uploading

Hey all i am in need of some help with this code in order for it to upload the correct size image plus a corresponding thumbnail for it:

```
    $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
    $new_file_path = $options['upload_dir'].$file_name;
    list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($file_path);

    if (!$img_width || !$img_height) {
        return false;
    }

    $scale = min(
        $options['max_width'] / $img_width,
        $options['max_height'] / $img_height
    );

    if ($scale > 1) {
        $scale = 1;
    }

    $new_width = 1280; //$new_width = $img_width * $scale;
    $new_height = 323; //$new_height = $img_height * $scale;        
    $new_img = @imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    switch (strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1))) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $src_img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagejpeg';
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $src_img = @imagecreatefromgif($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagegif';
            break;
        case 'png':
            $src_img = @imagecreatefrompng($file_path);
            $write_image = 'imagepng';
            break;
        default:
            $src_img = $image_method = null;
    }

    $success = $src_img && @imagecopyresampled(
        $new_img,
        $src_img,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        $new_width,
        $new_height,
        $img_width,
        $img_height
    ) && $write_image($new_img, $options['upload_dir'] . $_GET['type'] . '.' . strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1)), 100);

    @imagedestroy($src_img);
    @imagedestroy($new_img);
```

I've tried to add this:

```
    $success = $src_img && @imagecopyresampled(
        $new_img,
        $src_img,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        192,
        50,
        $img_width,
        $img_height
    ) && $write_image($new_img, $options['upload_dir'] . $_GET['type'] . 'THUMB.' . strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1)), 100);
```

But it just copies the same image twice with the same height and width as the first one:

```
Bob.jpg         800kb
BobTHUMB.jpg    800kb
```

Comment: Let me ask you a question. Why do people post all their code to SO when they have problem instead of creating small test script to help us help you?

Comment: if i did that.... it would be a very long line of code to post which would in turn turn off people helping seeing a whole 350 lines of code :)

Comment: No, I don't mean the merge of above code into one line. You're having a problem creating thumbnail? Create test script with sample image that should call several functions to show us what you are trying to achieve. It really won't be longer than 10 LOC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$thm_img = @imagecreatetruecolor( 192, 50 );

$success = $src_img && @imagecopyresampled(
   $thm_img,
   $src_img,
   0, 0, 0, 0,
   192,
   50,
   $img_width,
   $img_height
) && $write_image($thm_img, $options['upload_dir'] . $_GET['type'] . 'THUMB.' . strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1)), 100);
```

Comment: Happy to help! The problem was the `$new_img` resource was already allocated at 1280x323 dimensions :)